# jQueryUI's Autocomplete doesn't understand JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui

I have this JSON array:

```
[
    {"name":"Mario Kart Wii"},
    {"name":"Super Mario Galaxy 2"},
    {"name":"Super Mario Galaxy"},
    {"name":"Mario Sports Mix"},
    {"name":"Mario & Sonic at the Olympic Winter Games"}
]
```

Pretty much simple.

And my jQuery code:

```
$('#searchFieldGame').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            console.log(response)
            $.getJSON('/index.php/search/autocomplete/'+request['term'],response)
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#searchFieldGame').val(ui.item.value);
            $('#searchFormGame').submit()
        },
        minLength: 3
    })
```

My problem is - when JSON is simpler, eg:

```
[
    "Mario Kart Wii",
    "Super Mario Galaxy 2",
    "Super Mario Galaxy",
    "Mario Sports Mix",
    "Mario & Sonic at the Olympic Winter Games"
 ]
```

It works great. But if it's more like the first one, it doesn't get any results. I need to keep it like the first one, because I want more elements in every array later.

Comment: I don;t follow the comments about "I want more elements in every array later."  You can have as many array elements as you want, they just have to be keyed (or left without key) according to the acceptable formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For jQuery UI autocomplete, there are only two acceptable data formats.

```
['item', 'item2', 'item3', ...]
[{label: 'item', value: 'itemvalue'}, {label: 'item2', value: 'itemvalue2'}, ... ]
```

Comment: those are the 2 formats  , but it allows you do add additional properities if you need to - I usually add "id"  along with "label" and "value"

Comment: `[{label:'item'}]` and `[{value:'value'}]` are also valid, in either case, the one will be used for both just like in the array only version.

Comment: @KevinB  and Scott - Good thoughts.  Those formats are actually not reflected in the official documentation.

Comment: @MikeBrant Oh but they are! http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source *"If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the label."* As far as additional properties, that's just due to how objects work. Additional properties won't cause it to break, they'll just be ignored. But you knew that.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an array of objects, it must at least have value and/or label properties. [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

```
[
    {"value":"Mario Kart Wii"},
    {"value":"Super Mario Galaxy 2"},
    {"value":"Super Mario Galaxy"},
    {"value":"Mario Sports Mix"},
    {"value":"Mario & Sonic at the Olympic Winter Games"}
]
```

If that isn't an option, you can use `$.map` to fix it.

```
$.getJSON('/index.php/search/autocomplete/'+request['term'],function(data){
    response( $.map(data,function(obj) {
        return obj.name;
    }) );
});
```